# View field nesting

Tags: views, 8

I need some help. I have view with two fields

- Featured image
- 2.Logo

normally Drupal renders is as separate divs
what i want is to nest the 2nd div to the 1st div

**Normal Drupal render**

```
<div class= "views-name-featured-image"> Featured Image </div>
<div class= "views-name-logo"> Featured Image </div>
```

**what I want is**

```
<div class= views-name-featured-image> 

   Featured Image goes here

      <div class= views-name-logo> 

         Logo goes here

   </div>
</div>
```

Views field-set is not available for Drupal 8

How can I achieve this... rewriting the result is not working too.

Comment: Well, you can access value of your fileds directly on parent template. I think that is only way to do this. BUT, for me, its not a good practice, it is better, you write a field with this two values and create a template for this field. Piece of cake.

Answer (score -1):

Resolve by rewriting results on view... thanks anyways